# box.com authorization with over sockes

Tags: box-api

please help me authorize with direct sockets on box.com
my software uses socket communication

to get authorization code I'm sending client_id

`http.HTTPMethodWithRedirect('POST',
        'https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=omrtodqahh6cj9i2w9hytnvmlqdiivvt','','')`

but getting back a webpage, not JSON code that i expect.

Answer (score 0):

Box will always return a webpage after the first leg of the oauth process. Your application won't receive an authorization_code until after a user has logged into their account with valid Box credentials and accepted the oath2 grant for your app. More info here http://developers.box.com/oauth/